# How to create a multidimensional array out of an array and perform a filtering?

Tags: php, multidimensional-array

My goal is to keep all my array values in another array but I don't know how can I do that.
Here's my simple array:

```
$grand_total = $total + $cost;
$cost_ratio = ($cost/$grand_total) * 100;
$paid_ratio = ($total/$grand_total) * 100;

$info[] = array(
             'id' => $data['id'],
             'ratio' => $cost_ratio,
             'status' => $status 
          );
```

Here's my sample array output

```
Array
(
[0] => Array
    (
        [id] => 53
        [ratio] => 100
        [status] => C
    )

[1] => Array
    (
        [id] => 57
        [ratio] => 100
        [status] => I
    )

[2] => Array
    (
        [id] => 60
        [ratio] => 1.3157894736842
        [status] => I
    )
```

After creating an array the next thing to do is to filter this by getting the ratio.
As you have seen above I have a variable `$cost_ratio`, this variable is the one that will filter my array.

Here's the continuation of my code:

```
 //declare a variable
 $var1 = 0;
 $var2 = 0;
 $var3 = 0;
 $var4 = 0;
 $var5 = 0;
 $var6 = 0;
 $var7 = 0;
 $var8 = 0;
 $var9 = 0;
 $var10 = 0;
```

After that

```
  for($x = 0; $x < sizeof($info); $x++){

            $status_info = $info[$x]['status'];
            $temp = $info[$x]['ratio'];

            /*this will set my filter*/

            /*if temp <= 9, i need to put all of my array that has a ratio <= 9*/

            if($temp <= 9){
                $var1++;
            }else if($temp <= 19){
                $var2++;
            }else if($temp <= 29){
                $var3++;
            }else if($temp <= 39){
                $var4++;
            }else if($temp <= 49){
                $var5++;
            }else if($temp <= 59){
                $var6++;
            }else if($temp <= 69){
                $var7++;
            }else if($temp <= 79){
                $var8++;
            }else if($temp <= 89){
                $var9++;
            }else{
                $var10++;
            }

      }
```

And lastly the table for displaying my records

```
  echo "<table border='1'>";

        echo "<tr>";
            echo "<td>PERCENTAGE RANGE</td>";
            echo "<td>VOLUME</td>";
            echo "<td>RATIO</td>";
            echo "<td>BACKORDERED</td>";
            echo "<td>CANCELED</td>";
            echo "<td>COD APPROVED</td>";
            echo "<td>COD PENDING</td>";
            echo "<td>COD SHIPPED</td>";
            echo "<td>COMPLETED</td>";
            echo "<td>DECLINED</td>";
            echo "<td>FAILED</td>";
            echo "<td>FRAUD CHECKING</td>";
            echo "<td>PAID & WAITING SHIPPING</td>";
            echo "<td>PENDING</td>";
            echo "<td>SHIPPED</td>";
            echo "<td>TEST</td>";
            echo "<td>WAITING FOR APPROVAL</td>";
            echo "<td>WAITING PAYMENT</td>";
        echo "</tr>";

        echo "<tr>";
            echo "<td>10% - 90%</td>";
            echo "<td>".$var1."</td>"; <!-- IF ratio has a value between 1 - 9 go here -->
            echo "<td></td>";
            echo "<td>".$x1."</td>";
            echo "<td>".$x2."</td>";
            echo "<td>".$x3."</td>";
            echo "<td>".$x4."</td>";
            echo "<td>".$x5."</td>";
            echo "<td>".$x6."</td>";
            echo "<td>".$x7."</td>";
            echo "<td>".$x8."</td>";
            echo "<td>".$x9."</td>";
            echo "<td>".$x10."</td>";
            echo "<td>".$x11."</td>";
            echo "<td>".$x12."</td>";
            echo "<td>".$x13."</td>";
            echo "<td>".$x14."</td>";
            echo "<td>".$x15."</td>";          
        echo "</tr>";

        echo "<tr>";
            echo "<td>20% - 80%</td>"; <!-- IF ratio has a value between 10 - 19 go here -->
            echo "<td>".$var2."</td>";
            echo "<td></td>";
            echo "<td>".$x1."</td>";
            echo "<td>".$x2."</td>";
            echo "<td>".$x3."</td>";
            echo "<td>".$x4."</td>";
            echo "<td>".$x5."</td>";
            echo "<td>".$x6."</td>";
            echo "<td>".$x7."</td>";
            echo "<td>".$x8."</td>";
            echo "<td>".$x9."</td>";
            echo "<td>".$x10."</td>";
            echo "<td>".$x11."</td>";
            echo "<td>".$x12."</td>";
            echo "<td>".$x13."</td>";
            echo "<td>".$x14."</td>";
            echo "<td>".$x15."</td>";          
        echo "</tr>";
 .
 .
```

Here's what I want to do:

```
[ratio between 1 - 9 value] = array(
     [0] = array(
              'id' => 1,
              'status' => 'C'
           ),
     [1] = array(
              'id' => 3,
              'status' => 'D'
           ),
     [2] = array(
              'id' => 6,
              'status' => 'J'
           ),

),

[ratio between 10 - 19 value] = array(
     [0] = array(
              'id' => 1,
              'status' => 'C'
           ),
     [1] = array(
              'id' => 3,
              'status' => 'D'
           ),
     [2] = array(
              'id' => 6,
              'status' => 'J'
           ),

),
.
.
.
```

That's what I want to do but I am having a hard time with that.

Comment: This is pretty a long question and confusing what you want to do. Do you want to group `ratio` in specific range or the question is other thing?

Comment: yes i want to group it by ratio value

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can easily group array by doing like the following:

```
$array = array(
    array( 'id' => 53, 'ratio' => 100, 'status' => 'I'),
    array( 'id' => 54, 'ratio' => 50, 'status' => 'C'),
    array( 'id' => 56, 'ratio' => 42, 'status' => 'D')
);

// Grouping array by ratio
$group = array();
foreach($array as $value) {
    $groupIndex = min($value['ratio'] / 10, 9);
    $group[$groupIndex][] = $value;
}

var_dump($group);
```

Here is the sample output

```
array (size=3)
  9 => 
    array (size=1)
      0 => 
        array (size=3)
          'id' => int 53
          'ratio' => int 100
          'status' => string 'I' (length=1)
  5 => 
    array (size=1)
      0 => 
        array (size=3)
          'id' => int 54
          'ratio' => int 50
          'status' => string 'C' (length=1)
  4 => 
    array (size=1)
      0 => 
        array (size=3)
          'id' => int 56
          'ratio' => int 42
          'status' => string 'D' (length=1)
```

Noted that the index `9` means from 90+, `5` means from 50 to 59, and `4` means from 40 to 49. If you are confused with the index convention, here is the full list:

```
$group[0]   <--- from 0 to 9
$group[1]   <--- from 10 to 19
$group[2]   <--- from 20 to 29
$group[3]   <--- from 30 to 39
$group[4]   <--- from 40 to 49
$group[5]   <--- from 50 to 59
$group[6]   <--- from 60 to 69
$group[7]   <--- from 70 to 79
$group[8]   <--- from 80 to 89
$group[9]   <--- from 90+
```

Comment: in grouping array by ratio do i need to change the value of /10,9?

Comment: Depends on what you want, if you want to group ratio by group of 10, you should stick with my code.